HP_LaserJet_P2035?serial=RZ4EWEM
I am using Ubuntu 20.04. I have a USB connected HP_LaserJet_P2035? that won't print. I had it working for a while with the HP provided software provided by HP for Linux. It was working well, but I don't use it often.
I recently needed it and it will not print. It's a software issue, perhaps a driver. I've tried updating the software but no help. It often says it's out of paper but it isn't. It lights the out of paper light on the printer. However, running it under Windows it operates and prints fine with no issues.
I use dual boot, Ubuntu and Windows 7. I have had ongoing trouble with the HP software in the past and I'm tired of working on it.
Is there a way that I can remove the HP software and run this printer with something generic in Ubuntu? I'm no expert. Thanks.

This question is similar to: Printer problems after installing Ubuntu 20.04. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I was thinking of uninstalling the software for this printer and was doing a search on how to do it, but instead I found a fix. I performed the steps shown on this page: https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/07/install-latest-hplip-ubuntu-20-04-fix/. Apparently there was a dependency issue with the old software. The printer is working now, so far. Time will tell if it continues to, but I think this will be successful. If anyone has this issue, I hope this helps!
